# In Unity, a rigidbody automatically integrates all child colliders. How can I have a hitbox on the object/childeren that isn't used by the rigidbody?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, raycasting

In order to be a rigidbody, my pirate ship collider has to be convex (unity gives me errors when it's not). I have a more detailed (non-convex) collider that i want to use for raycasts within the boat, but when i add it as a child object, the rigidbody automatically tries to use it.

Is there a way that i can have a seperate mesh collider as a child of a rigidbody? Any work-arounds?

Putting the detailed mesh on a seperate layer doesn't work. The only thing i can think of is making the ship out of many seperate convex colliders, but this is a solution that i want to avoid, as getting smooth internal curves would require many, many colliders.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: When raycasting, you can ignore layers using LayerMask.

Comment: `Any work-arounds?` -> The alternative would be to simply make your special collider object follow the Rigibody without being a child of it (`private void Update(){transform.position = rigidbody.position; transform.rotation = rigibody.rotation; }`) and put it on a special layer you can configure to not ever interfere with the Rigidbody

Comment: @derHugo I hadn't thought of this, thanks I'll give it a try. My only worry is that it will end up a frame out of sync if the following object's script updates after the raycasts instead of before. It might be just what i need though.

Comment: @HasnainShaukat I've tried this but the rigidbody still tries to incorporate the child's mesh, even if they are on different physics layers.

Comment: Then use `LateUpdate` to be sure ;)

Comment: @derHugo I've finally got around to implementing your solution and i just wanted to update you on it. After a little bit of tinkering with physics layers, it works a treat! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Another solution would be to make it its own Rigidbody and then use a FixedJoint to make it follow the main object without being a child of it